# Oracle DB Authentication Prioritization

Tags: oracle, authentication

If an Oracle authentication service has been configured, such as SecurID, does this mean that local users using Username/Password cannot use these credentials to login?

From this link it appears as that is the case but I was hoping to get some confirmation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/net/doc/NWANO233/ch3.htm

Comment: Typically a database account can only be authenticated by a single means: username/password *or* some other external authentication (AD, LDAP, PKI, OAM, etc).

Comment: @pmdba Thanks! Does this mean that an account with username/password cannot log in if an external authenticator is set. Or that the authentication would only be conducted through the local username/password validation?

Comment: @pmdba - just to clarify, I believe that is "a _given_ database account can only be authenticated ....."  So one account could authenticate by username/password (only) and another by LDAP (only), etc. Also worth noting that the OP's cited source appears (based on page layout,etc) to be from a much older version (10g or earlier, but I was not able to drill back to find out exactly which.

Comment: @EdStevens Thank you!

Comment: It's what @edstevens said: a *given* account can only have one authentication method. You can have different accounts with different authentication methods in the same database instance.